# Password Recovery in Blueprism

Tags: blueprism

I have username admin. But now I forget my password.I want to reset my password in blue prism. How to recover my password?

Answer (score 12):

This isn't the official script distributed by Blue Prism (as @Jerry pointed out the existence of), but one I've used against several installations to force a reset of the password.

---

#### Blue Prism v6

This finds the user with the username `admin` and resets their password back to the original `admin` string. It will force a password change for `admin` on their next logon.

```
USE blueprism
UPDATE BPAPassword SET salt = '', hash = '208512264222772174181102151942010236531331277169151', type = 0
WHERE userid = (SELECT userid FROM BPAUser WHERE username = 'admin')
```

#### Blue Prism v5

This script will change **every** user in the environment's password back to `admin`, but will *not* force a password change on the next log in. There is likely a more elegant way to do this and target just the `admin` user, but unfortunately I no longer have access to a v5 schema to test this on.

```
USE blueprism
UPDATE BPAUser
SET password = '208512264222772174181102151942010236531331277169151'
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the script solution, you can also manually update the `BPAPassword` table using *SQL Server Object Explorer* (built-in in Visual Studio) to reset password to `admin` as follows:

- find the desired user in the `BPAUser` table and copy `userid`
- find the row with same `userid` inside `BPAPassword` table
- update following columns

> `type` -> `0`
>
> `salt` -> `''`
>
> `hash` -> `208512264222772174181102151942010236531331277169151`

[image]

or use the following script:

```
UPDATE [BluePrismDefault].[dbo].[BPAPassword]
SET [type] = 0,
    [salt] = '',
    [hash] = '208512264222772174181102151942010236531331277169151';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the password by running a query in the MS SQL Database in which BluePrism stores everything it uses. As for what query that is, it looks like it depends on the version of BluePrism, per [this page](https://help.blueprism.com/Installation-Platform/Configuration/Roles-and-Permissions/1143318442/How-can-I-reset-my-Blue-Prism-admin-password.htm):

> **How can I reset my Blue Prism admin password?**
>
> If you forget your Blue Prism admin password and/or exceed the maximum number of allowed login attempts, then please contact `support@blueprism.com` for details on how to request the relevant admin password reset scripts.
>
> We have several scripts which you can use to reset the password for the 'Admin' account. The script command is specific to the version of Blue Prism you are using.
>
> *Important: These scripts should only be run by a Database Administrator or someone who has an understanding of SQL.*

Answer (score -1):

You can just enter admin as user and admin as password. Thereafter you are redirected to a window that will allow you to enter a new password.

Comment: Not likely to work if the default password was changed!

Answer (score -1):

If it is an enterprise level then, you need to raise ticket to IT team. They will reset the password and inform you.

If Blue Prism is installed on local machine with local database credentials then there is an trick to reset it.

Irrespective of the version, you can follow the same steps. As I have version 6. below screen shots are with respect to version 6. But the fundamental tasks will be the same.

Steps are as below:

As we know While installing Blue Prism on the system, It will ask for the connection. Considering the "Default connection" password needs to be reset. Follow the following steps:

1. Click on Blue Prism icon
2. Click on `Configure` link on login window below window will appear

[image]

3. Click on `New Connection` button. Following window will appear with default connection name. In my case it is `connection2`

[image]

As this steps need to be carried out on local machine, use the local database instance name as `Database server` and give name `Database Name`

Fill the required details, and click on `Create Database`. Once the Database created successfully, just ensure once again click on `Test Connection` and validate the connection establishment between Blue Prism and SQL Server

Note: In the SQL Database, database will be created with the name given in `Database Name` field

4. Open SQL Server Instance, you'll be finding the `Database Name` (value mentioned in field)created.
5. Navigate to `Database Name` --> Tables--> BPAPassword and hit the following query
   `Select * from BPAPassword`. In the output table, `salt` and `hash` the main two column for which we are looking for.

Note: We're doing this, as we know when we install Blue Prism and try for login the initial `username` and `password` will be `admin`. As soon as, we login with the default credential it will ask for change password.

Blue prism will store all the values in encrypted mode in Database, So decryption of the values will be impossible as human.

As this is a new connection for Blue Prism, for this connection default password will be `admin`

Now, Copy the value of `salt` and `hash`.

6. Connect the database which is used for `Default connection`. And update the `salt` and `hash` column in `BPAPAassword` Table using the SQL Update statement for specific user.

Note: If you've multiple users then, goto `BPAUser` and find the user for which you need to reset the password.

*NOTE: This will be carried out only on local machine. If it happened within organization please connect to IT team to password reset. Please do not create the database on the organization database server as it may affect the Blue Prism server which is configured already as per organization requirement*

Comment: This answer requires re-work to make it clear that the "*SQL Update statement for specific user*" is specifically to change the `salt`/`hash` fields to values extracted in step 5. Additionally: "*If it happened within organization please connect to IT team to password reset*" - what if the organization in question doesn't have an IT team assigned to maintaining the underlying database? Even in these types of environments, users with the "User Roles" permission will be able to change a user's password within the environment in a significantly more elegant and less risky way.