# Forgotten BluePrism Admin password

Tags: blueprism

I have a script from BluePrism to reset my "admin" password. It is the Learning edition 6.9.0.

What I can't figure out is how to actually apply that script to the BluePrism database.

I have MySql installed on my PC and I was hoping I could that to run the scripts, but I can't find an option to connect MySql to the blueprism database.

I can find the BluePrism database no problem, but MySql won't recognise it as a database file.

I have also tried setting up a new connection inside BluePrism itself but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You seem to be confused - Blue Prism doesn't support MySQL, only SQL Server (and its various flavors). It's not exactly clear what you're referring to when you refer to the "database file". Whatever script you got for resetting the password should be executed on the SQL Server database you set up for your initial training environment. This is usually done through Microsoft's proprietary SQL Server Management Studio client.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password Recovery in Blueprism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325543/password-recovery-in-blueprism)

Comment: I have since installed MS SQL Server but the problem I have now is that SQL Server Management Studio can't see the Blueprism.mdf file. The mdf file is in a sub-directory off C:\Users\<my-name>\AppData ..... However when I try to connect with the mdf file, SMSS can't see past the my-name sub-directory. I have tried making that sub-directory not Read-Only but with no success.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio generally isn't used to open `*.mdf` files, it primarily connects to active SQL Server instances (however it appears there may be [some methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297097/attach-open-mdf-file-database-with-sql-server-management-studio) you can use to accomplish this). In regards to your comment "*I have since installed MS SQL Server*", can you elaborate on this? How exactly were you able to successfully install Blue Prism without having SQL Server (or one of its flavors, like SQL Server Express) installed prior to this point...?

Comment: I had SQL Server already installed. I have since installed it again to get the SMSS elements so I could hopefully run the scripts against the mdf file.

Comment: In that case, why not just connect to your local instance of SQL Server and save the headaches of trying to open the database file itself? To re-iterate, opening the database from an `*.mdf` file to make changes is generally speaking not standard procedure with SQL Server.

Comment: I have solved my problem. I copied the mdf file and log into the default data directory in SQL Server, changed them there and then copied them back again. A kludge I know but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325543/password-recovery-in-blueprism) that works for me.

> This isn't the official script distributed by Blue Prism (as @Jerry
> pointed out the existence of), but one I've used against several
> installations to force a reset of the password.
>
> Blue Prism v6 This finds the user with the username admin and resets
> their **password back to the original admin string**. It will force a
> password change for admin on their next login.

```
USE blueprism
UPDATE BPAPassword SET salt = '', hash = '208512264222772174181102151942010236531331277169151', type = 0
WHERE userid = (SELECT userid FROM BPAUser WHERE username = 'admin')
```

Also here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeRZ0X3jsEs) with another process that changes it to another password, maybe you could try it, if the first solution does not work or if you like a more visual resource.